# SP 2010 , SP 2013 and SQL Database

Tags: 2010, 2013, sql

Can Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2013 use the same database (SQL 2012) ?

Comment: You mean Database server?

Comment: yea share same content db ?

Comment: Sharing the same database will not work.

Comment: Sorry let me correct - We need sp2010 and sp 2013 to be installed . We have configured SQL 2012 . Why cant we use SQL 2012 for work with SP2010 and 2013 ?

Comment: You can make it work.. but you said you need to use the same database. We cant share database rather we can share database server

Comment: thx for quick response . .

Comment: this one is good for testing/dev farm but not recommended for the Production farm.

Comment: yea considering for dev and test only . Prod have 2 seperate boxes . Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can leverage the same database server across multiple installs.

The only thing you should take care of is to use unique "Database" names so it will not conflict with each other.

For example:

Append "SP2010" to all databases that are created for SharePoint 2010.

Also you should increase the server capacity to support both.

[Sharepoint 2010 and 2013 on same SQL Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118579/sharepoint-2010-and-2013-on-same-sql-server)